# Remove Hyperlink format in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm currently working on a report in which one of the textboxes has the action property of launching another report. I would love to now how to remove the hyperlink like format to the text.

I already setted the text decorations to **None**. Texbotx and text effects also to **None** and still, everytime i upload the report an start running it, the textbox has that damn underlining

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: Thats odd... I don't get underlining on my linked report. Just to confirm, you right-click text box properties, action, Go to report? And under properties for the text box, Font, TextDecoration is set to None?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Also effects are set to None for texbox, text and placeholder. and also fontstyle is set to normal

Comment: Just checking...is your textbox Action property still set to "go to report", but you don't want it to look like a hyperlink?

Comment: @DeanOC that's exactly what I need

Comment: This post seems to have the exact opposite problem of yours, so it would seem possible to achieve what you want https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1379201/Hyperlink-of-Go-to-Report-is-not-Display-with-Blue-and-underline-in-report--used-expression-for-report-path . Perhaps if you set up your textbox in a similar fashion, i.e. use expression to get the ReportName, you may get the desired result.

Comment: @DeanOC tried the same thing but it didn't work

Comment: Very strange, all I can suggest is attempting to re-create the situation in as simple a report as possible, i.e. build a brand new minimal report and add a URL and see what happens. I assume you are using the Visual Studio Report Designer? If so what version of VS?

Comment: @DeanOC ok, sorry. It actually worked, but before I had to delete a few blank spaces that where manually added before the placeholder

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the placeholder *within* the textbox, and then right-click, you should see 'Placeholder Properties...' menu item.

[image]

On the General tab, select Markup type 'None'.

Comment: Yes. It was the default value

Comment: Somewhat ironically, setting the Markup type to HTML is actually what seems to remove the hyperlink formatting, in my situation at least

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue for an SSRS report rendered through the browser, even though rendering through Report Builder (2016) was fine. 
It was the OP's comment about spaces and DeanOC's answer that helped me figure out the issue.

The issue seems to indicate a bug with program.  Whenever you put spaces (either spaces or you use the Left Indent) in front of the placeholder, it will render the textbox (if there is an *Action => Got To Report* on the Textbox) with an underline.

The workaround to get the required behaviour (no underline for indented text), is to put the *Action => Go To Report* under the placeholder.  I set the Action to Nothing for the textbox.  *Font => Effects* was set to Default or None for the Textbox/Placeholder.  And the Markup Type (which is a property of the placeholder and not a Textbox) was set to none. 
Nb. the Indent does seem to be a common property of the Placeholder and Textbox.